# Monocle: Error in RANN::nn2(data, data, k + 1, searchtype = "standard") : no points in data

Tags: r, seurat

I'm trying to subset a dataset from Seurat3 object for trajectory using Monocle (not Monocle3) as follows:

```
mono <- subset(Seurat.combined,idents=c(0,2,3,5))
```

Then constructed monocle CDS(mono_cds) using newCellDataSet, and I got an error when I call the reduceDimension:

```
mono_cds <- reduceDimension(mono_cds, max_components = 2,
                        reduction_method = "DDRTree")

DDRTree will be eventually deprecated in reduceDimension call and be used in learnGraph function instead. We are calling learnGraph for you now.
Error in RANN::nn2(data, data, k + 1, searchtype = "standard") : 
  no points in data!
In addition: Warning message:
In (function (data, pd, k = 20, weight = F, louvain_iter = 1, resolution = NULL,  :RANN counts the point itself, k must be smaller than
the total number of points - 1 (all other points) - 1 (itself)!
Timing stopped at: 0.008 0 0.008
```

The issue may be caused by the subset of Seurat object, if I don't subset the dataset and use the whole Seurat3 object to constructed monocle CDS, there is no problem.

I am using monocle_2.99.3 and Seurat 3.1.2.

Any help? Thanks!